# move module's external .js file code to template [phtml] file

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, javascript, xml

We have a custom module with below code

`app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/layout/aitcg.xml`

```
<action method="addJs"><script>aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js</script></action>
```

As **we can't use php code in this .JS file**, is there any way we can move code present from `Abstract.js` file to some `.phtml` file ?

**Edit**

I followed Raphael's answer & changed code as here :

```
<block type="aitcg/template" name="aitcg_js_styles1" template="aitcg/js_styles1.phtml" />
```

but still Abstract.Js file results are not displaying in js_styles1.phtml

**layout file** : http://pastebin.com/BZGRaiDH

**js_styles1.phtml** : http://pastebin.com/m85q9eMh

i am trying onclick button = `onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();"` but this is not working in .JS file , so only i am trying to cop .js code to .php code.

```
<script>

_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button  id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();">SAVE DESIGN</button>' +
                '<button  id="submit-editorReset-{{rand}}" >{{reset_text}}</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

    </script>
```

when i checked template path hints, it loading phtml file, but JS code result is not displaying in frontend. but other html, php, js code results are displaying.....

**console**

[image]

[image]

is we need to load any external js library if so how to find that ?

**Edit2**

I tried Below code in js_styles1.phtml file , but still its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/js/aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js"></script>
```

Comment: i will give 50 bounty points if it worked for me.....

Comment: What php code you want to use in your js file? You can use javascript code to do the same thing as php code.

Comment: @NehaRaval i want to display pop up if guest clicked on the button & i dont want to display pop up registered user clicked on that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` is called on your `head.phtml`.

If *this code is not exits then you need  add this code at head.phtml*

### Update

You have getting issue becauase of

**Js dependency on  one js files to another js file**

Here *aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Popup.js,aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Gallery.js* , etc depends on js code of *aitcg/js_styles.phtml*

As you have put  this ***Abstract.js at js_styles.phtml*** and this `js file  properly have calling after`

```
    aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Popup.js
    aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Gallery.js
    aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Gallery_Rwd.js
    aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/Editor/Canvas/Abstract.js
    aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/Editor/Canvas.js
    aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/Editor/Canvas/Mirror.js
    .....
   ...
    aitoc/aitcg/raphael.js
    aitoc/aitcg/jscolor/jscolor.js
    aitoc/aitcg/rgbcolor.js
    aitoc/aitcg/canvg.js
```

That  **means all js file of   aitoc does not getting** `properly of   js_styles.phtml` as this **js code is after all** 
 aitoc js files.

**Solution:**

**Remove all js  files of Aitoc** layout handler `<catalog_product_view>`

and call those all ***js fils at js_styles.phtml manually code***

```
<!--  code of aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js -->

....
<!--  end of aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js -->


<?php
/* check current page is product */
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() =='catalog_product_view'){  ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Popup.js')?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Gallery.js')?>"></script>
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/AreaEditor.js')?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('aitoc/aitcg/raphael.js')?>"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('aitoc/aitcg/canvg.js')?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes, `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` code is present in head.phtml file.....

Comment: also we added this code in view.phtml : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('aitcg_js_styles1'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for your priceless time & support, its working absolutely fine...... i willl award bounty to you......

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use a phtml file instead by replacing:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js</script></action>
```

With:

```
<block type="core/template" name="custom.js" template="my/custom/template.phtml" />
```

Then just move your JS in that phtml file and tweak it with your PHP modifications.

Comment: Thanks , its nice to see your answer for my question again....  I followed your answer & replaced `action code`by `block code` as here : `<block type="aitcg/template" name="aitcg_js_styles1" template="aitcg/js_styles1.phtml" />` , but Its not displaying results of `.js file - upload image & add text buttons are missing` as in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) , before those links were displaying as [link2](http://stylebaby.com/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) , code : `js_styles1.phtml : http://pastebin.com/YhgmvCMx .  where i done wrong ?

Comment: here is layout.xml file : http://pastebin.com/dbu9thPE  , please check once.....

Comment: I can see "upload image" and "add text" buttons in both links, and different errors in console. Have you solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

as i understand your question, you want to copy your js code in phtml

so, follow below steps

as you already created a PHTML file and its rendering on frontend

firstly comment/remove that XML code for JS rendering.

Copy JS code to PHTML file within script TAG

for ex.

```
<script>
 your js file code here 
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, yes i copied javascript code present in  .js file to phtml file..... but its giving me console errors

Comment: First just copy paste js code and check that it is working and then modify the code

Comment: when i copy js code to phtml code, i cant see any results of .js code - "upload image and add text button " missing after i copied code

Comment: add your phtml file in head

Comment: you get this error bcause your js file is in body

Comment: let me check that.....

Comment: i added script code inside head, but still same issue : http://pastebin.com/357c9W6L

Comment: result when code was in .js file : [link1](http://stylebaby.com/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) , result when i copied to .phtml file : [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Comment: dont add this JS just after head

Comment: is i need to use any external js library in head section, i dont know what to do.....

Comment: this JS uses prototype.js

Comment: so declare after prototype js but before head end

Comment: sorry i didt got : `dont add just after head this js`

Comment: read again  .............

Comment: i added like : `<html<head><script>  </script> </head> </html>` is ths correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55636/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Answer (score 1):

Delete the actual java you pasted out of the head file.

Paste one of these into the head of your phtml file, depending on where your js file is located.

If it is located in Magento's base js file use this:

```
<script src="<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or if it is in your skin's js folder use this:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>js/aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but still it showing console errors as posted in question.....

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can pass your PHP code variable to your JS code using config variable.
Add below line to your file **app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/template/aitcg/view/options/‌​type/cgfile.phtml**

```
isUserLoggedIn : '<?php echo (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())? "true": "false"; ?>',
```

after line,

```
jsUrl: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);?>',  
editorEnabled: true,
```

Now you can use this variable `isUserLoggedIn` to check if user is logged in or not in your JS code.
Update your JS function `initObservers`, from

```
initObservers: function() 
{ 
if (this.config.editorEnabled) { 
$('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
$('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
} 
},
```

to

```
initObservers: function() 
{ 
if (this.config.editorEnabled && this.config.isUserLoggedIn == 'true') { 
$('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
$('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
} 
},
```

Now when a guest user will click on "Save Design" button, the design will not save and it will open your login popup you used in your code,

```
<div onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\');setrequestlogin();"> 
<button class="button btn-cart">Save design</button> 
</div>
```